# iphone SDK:Can write data to plist on Simulator but can't do same thing at Device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, plist

Why I can write information to plist on simulator

But can't do this on real iphone/ipod device ????

Is there exist an absolute path to put a .plist file in xcode project ???

Thanks for all reply and answers ~

code : this how I write text to plist from textfield

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Password" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *propertyList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
[propertyList setValue:serialNumber.text forKey:@"serial_number"];
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where are you trying to write to this plist? What sort of data does it contain? What goes wrong?

Comment: OK，I will post the code how I write success on simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only write to your application's sandbox directory. Below is a function that will return the path to the Documents folder for you app.

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Comment: OK...I think I need to check how to create a plist file use code.and give a elements in the file,thanks !

Comment: You should probably place this wherever you need to get the path to the documents directory in order to either read or save the file you are trying to access. Placing it in the app delegate isn't a bad idea because it will allow you to access the method from anywhere in the app.