# writing to plist file not writing

Tags: ios, int, plist, nsdictionary

I want to retrieve an integer from a plist file, increment it, and write it back to the plist file. Inside the "Levels.plist" file is a row with the key `LevelNumber`, and with a value of `1`.
I use this code to retrieve the value:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Levels.plist" ofType:@"plist"];;
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    lvl = [[plistDict objectForKey:@"LevelNumber"]intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i", [[plistDict objectForKey:@"LevelNumber"]intValue]);
```

When I run this, I get the console output of 0. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd assume that "`lvl`" is also returning 0... or, if you do "`NSNumber * lvlNumber = [plistDict objectForKey:@"LevelNumber"];`", is that a valid object or is it null?  And does "`plistDict`" actually load up with information?  If you "`NSLog`" it, do you see the entries for it?

Comment: I declare `lvl` as an integer at the top of the implementation. And as for the plistDict, the NSLog prints out the `[[plistDict objectForKey:@"LevelNumber"]intValue]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
          pathForResource:@"Levels.plist" ofType:@"plist"];

NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                          initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
lvl = [[plistDict objectForKey:@"LevelNumber"]intValue];
NSLog(@"%i", [[plistDict objectForKey:@"LevelNumber"]intValue]);
```

My guess is that NSBundle is returning nil for the `pathForResource:ofType:` call, unless you've actually named your file "Levels.plist.plist".

Keep in mind that if that method happens to return `nil`, the rest of your code can still proceed. Given a `nil` file path, the `NSMutableDictionary` will return nil, and subsequent calls to get objects out of the dictionary will also return `nil`, hence your logging call showing an output of 0.

Comment: so the `pathForResource` only takes the file name and not the extension?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to do a lot of error checking along the way.

Perhaps something like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Levels" ofType:@"plist"];
if(filePath)
{
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if(plistDict)
    {
        NSNumber * lvlNumber = [plistDict objectForKey:@"LevelNumber"];
        if(lvlNumber)
        {
            NSInteger lvl = [lvlNumber integerValue];

            NSLog( @"current lvl is %d", lvl );

            // increment the found lvl by one
            lvl++;

            // and update the mutable dictionary
            [plistDict setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: lvl] forKey: @"LevelNumber"];

            // then attempt to write out the updated dictionary
            BOOL success = [plistDict writeToFile: filePath atomically: YES];
            if( success == NO)
            {
                NSLog( @"did not write out updated plistDict" );
            }
        } else {
            NSLog( @"no LevelNumber object in the dictionary" );
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"plistDict is NULL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was that this method is not conventional for the actual device itself. What you need to do is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132477/iphone-sdkcan-write-data-to-plist-on-simulator-but-cant-do-same-thing-at-devic?rq=1), and [this website](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/) explains how to do this on the actual device